# Unexpected output when deleting object

Tags: python, python-3.x

When I try to delete one instance of a class, it causes unexpected output from the `__del__` method of another instance:

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        print('{0} has been born!'.format(self.name))

    def __str__(self):
        return '{0} is {1} years old'.format(self.name, self.age)

    def __del__(self):
        print('{0} is deleted!'.format(self.name))

p1 = Person("John", 20)
p2 = Person("Mary", 27)

print(p1)
print(p2)

del(p2)
```

Output is:

```
John has been born!
Mary has been born!
John is 20 years old
Mary is 27 years old
Mary is deleted!
John is deleted!
```

Why `"John is deleted!"`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

John is deleted because your script ends. All module globals are cleared at that point.

Just to be clear, it is not the `del` call that clears `Mary` here. `del` just clears the variable from the global namespace, which in turn decrements the reference count to that object. Once the reference count reaches 0, the `__del__` method is called and the object is cleared from memory.

But your script namespace is an object too; it is stored in `sys.modules` under the `__main__` key, and once it is done running, the Python interpreter exits and clears out all modules in `sys.modules`. This causes refenence counts to drop, and for `John` this means that it'll be cleared too.

You could add a `print` statement after `del(p2)`:

```
print('Script complete')
```

and you'll see that inserted between the `is deleted!` outputs:

```
Mary is deleted!
Script complete
John is deleted!
```

Comment: Thanks! It's almost clear. I need to going much deeper in theory.

Comment: A small addition: It is not guaranteed that `__del__` will ever be called.

Comment: @Matthias: indeed, for Python versions  < 3.4 if there is a circular reference involved then `__del__` methods are not called at all as the circular reference is never broken.